# Way to specify param for all commands executed

Tags: shell, command, parameter

I was wondering if there is a way to specify a mutual param for X amount of commands. E.g.

`sudo cmd1 cmd2 cm3 \ --help`

this obviously doesn't work, but I haven't seen anything in the manual. I'm assuming it can't be done, but didn't rule it out completely. If it doesn't exist, how can I go about making it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to use a loop:

```
for cmd in cmd1 cmd2 cmd3; do
    "$cmd" --help
done
```

Or write a little function for it (add this to your shell's initialization file, `~/.bashrc` if using bash):

```
runWithParam(){
    param="$1"
    shift
    for cmd; do 
      "$cmd" "$param"
    done
}
```

Then, run it with the parameter as the first parameter of the function:

```
runWithParam --help cmd1 cmd2 cmd3
```